# Javascript not working on localhost, but it is working on Live site

Tags: javascript, xampp, localhost

I am facing JavaScript problems on XAMPP Localhost. The Collapse Buttons, go to top button and jQuery news feed are not working on every site on my localhost.

But Facebook, Twitter, Plusone buttons load correctly from remote server i.e. from the respective Social Sites.

So, I think it narrows me to the point that the JavaScript files hosted locally are not executed while those from Facebook etc. are getting executed.

I tried reinstalling XAMPP but didn't work.

Comment: A code sample would be great!!

Comment: Could it be some same-origin restriction for XMLHTTPRequest?

Comment: Check in the Chrome Developer Tools Console for 404 errors - it could just be that your paths are incorrect.

Comment: @JLevett Take an Example of a Vbulletin.com , the Back to top and forum collapse buttons work fine. On My Website in localhost, it doesn't do anything. Same way I added a Jquery News ticker, which works in my live site but not on local host :(

KerrekSB - Sorry Bro, I don't understand that, Can you elaborate?

Dexter-I checked using Firebug and error console, everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not matter whether your files are local or not...javascript should still get executed. Try using some debugging tool like to see if you get any errors that only occur on your local machine. Because it could be that you are running some code that is depending on a domain or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did check that in Firebug, but still can't find what is the problem.

Comment: Try installing the webdeveloper toolbar...and see if that gives you a more meaningfull error message when running the page.

Comment: Hi Baszz, I installed the Web Developer add-on and got many errors but all were looking similar. one of the error is 

Reference to undefined Property f[h]

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: not true :) i mean js might fire locally, but e.g. our beloved g+1 button wont work on your local site ;) neither does the fb like button when customized with your own css stylesheets ;)

Comment: But the thing is that, in localhost i have installed many sites. All these sites too don't execute Local Javascript codes.

Comment: @Walialu I have Internet enabled eventhough I am testing it on Localhost.

Comment: @Manoj I was not flaming you for developing on a local machine ;) it was just to clarify that what Baszz stated is not 100% true :)

Comment: @Walialu Can you give me the Answer? I think you too have came too close to answer me. I am suffering from this problem since last week :(

Comment: @Manoj you already marked the answer given by baszz as "fixed my problem" but if you are really hoping to get this fixed paste a http://jsfiddle.net/ here.. it's pretty easy to do so and i can simply test why it might not run locally by copy and paste from there :)

Comment: Thanks for that Walialu I will certainly try that :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but, I had the same problem and found this question while searching a solution. But I have lampp installed on ubuntu and since Linux asks permission to execute ANYTHING, the local js files which resided in htdocs were without permission. After:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

... everything was  OK. Hope this helps future wanabee web developers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old and the answer is already given, I just wanted to give an answer of a possible reason that I encountered in case someone else finds this and it does not help.

Make sure your entire html code gets executed by viewing your page source. With me, half my code was not being executed due to a PHP error that was working on localhost with the local database but not on live with the live database. This caused the HTML to cut of from that point above my javascript.

So check your page source. If it is being cut of somewhere, find out why :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I try a lot  but finally solved.  The main problem was my browser cache that prevents from loading the new JavaScript file. My recommendation is that clear your browser cache data then close the browser and reopen your site again it will work perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

remove any (pre in post ) blank spaces from filenames  of  your  namespace     example :    localhost:port/dir   /index.html
             localhost:port/dir/index.html

Comment: in this example  the blank space is after dir.../  for this must be removed all the blank space  dir/  . or rename the filename .

Answer (score -1):

In similar cases,
If web project site runs JS on Live Server but not on locally opened index.html,
try to check validity of HTML File Paths,

e.g you may have written:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

Try to add ./ before file name.

./ means Current directory.

Comment: Not starting with a `/`, `?` or URL scheme *also* means "current directory" so that will not make a difference.